# Inject content script into old tabs when extension did launch with activeTab permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've got tired of long *Pending Review* messages in Chrome Web Store and decided to use `activeTab` permission instead of `tabs` and `<all_urls>` (my content script still matches `<all_urls>`).

manifest.json was:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content/index.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": true,
        "match_about_blank": true
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
],
```

and now is:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content/index.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": true,
        "match_about_blank": true
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
],
```

But now, when the app is installed or activated, the content script is injected into newly created tabs, but is not injected into old tabs.

Clicking the popup (or removing the popup and using the browser action) and injecting the script using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` works, but I find it inconvenient for users. Listening to `chrome.tabs.onActivated` or using `chrome.tabs.query({active: true})` doesn't let injecting the script without clicking on the icon.

Is there a way make a content script being injected into old tabs smoothly (at least when tab is activated) without broad permissions?

Comment: 1) See [Chrome extension: Checking if content script has been injected or not](//stackoverflow.com/q/34528785) 2)  "my content script still matches `<all_urls>`" - then nothing changed from the web store point of view and your extension stil has broad host permissions (technically it's true because your content script can do anything on any site so you can abuse extract sensitive info in the tabs or in an iframe inside extension background page).

Comment: @wOxxOm So, how to make it run smoothly (without icon click) without the broad permissions? And why adding `"permissions": ["activeTab", "<all_urls>"]` let's using the `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, but `["activeTab"]` does not even for active tabs?

Comment: 1) The only way is [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions), 2) see the bottom of [activeTab doc page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Comment: @wOxxOm Nice idea, thank you. Do you know why the content script, declared in manifest, is not injected into previously opened tabs?

Comment: Because that's how it works. You can inject them yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm What to do with long "Pending Review"?

Tonight I published a new extension, and today when I cancelled publishing to fix a typo in a description, it asked me to use a new dev console to answer questions like "why you need tabs permission, broad host, do you use remote scripts" etc and said it will be reviewed in several weeks. Mozilla just published it in a few hours.

So, what do you do to speed up an update? I understand if it happens for "Editors Choice". Every time I have to beg the support, showing the GitHub link, large count of users etc. But what if critical fix is needed?

Comment: The only way is to use the optional permissions and no `content_scripts` on all urls.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, we will see what the dev console will say. When I change the permissions.

Comment: @wOxxOm Are you a part of the team? How do they actually review the extensions? Firefox Add-ons team asks to submit the source code and building instructions, looks through the changes, asks questions if necessary. But it looks like CWS team just puts the extensions into the queue :) Even if there are no code changes after a week you have to write them to make the app being published the next day,

Maybe they could do a separate queue for popular open-source extensions? Especially when they are in "Editors Choice".

Comment: I'm not in any Google's team. I also think Google does a pretty lousy job at organizing all extensions-related activities like development of API and webstore reviews.